# Getting the class name which triggered the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tag with below HTML :

`<a href='#' class='create_account singup  header-icon'>Create Account</a>`

I am using a common click handler of the 3 button with Class `create_account` , `member_login` , `product_service`

Now inside the handler , I want the class name which triggered the click event, in best possible way (with minimal condition)

```
 $('.create_account , .member_login , .product_services').click(function(){


    console.log($(this).attr('class')); 

    /**

      In case , user click on button with class `create_account` , I get in console

      `create_account singup  header-icon` , which is correct, 

       **but I want `create_account` i.e is the class which triggered the Click event**

    */


 });
```

Comment: you can check class with [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), like `if ($(this).hasClass('create_account')) {...}`

Comment: @Drakes, is html really needed, In case needed then I can post that, but I don't feel like HTML is needed

Comment: I reread your question... not needed. Thanks

Comment: @Grundy , yes you are correct about the solution , but i am looking for a way in which I don't have to place such condition :) , In case there is no solution then surely your solution is the path which i need to follow

Comment: @sanjeev, as workaround you can use `data-` attribute where place class, like `<a href='#' class='create_account singup  header-icon' data-class='create_account'>`

Comment: Which class name? Is the real question. There are 3 classes on that element, which one do you want to evaluate?

Comment: As an alternative work around, move the handler to a separate function and provide multiple event handlers, eg `$(".create").click(function() { commonHandler("create"); });

Comment: I want the evaluation to be according to the class name which has binded event , for example in our case inside the click event I want `create_account`

Comment: @freedomn-m can you specify your approach more clearly

Comment: Yes, that (coincidentally) is the first class on the element, but there are 2 others. How do we tell the code that it is the first you want? Is it because it's the first?

Comment: @JayMee , that class can be inbetween too , in future there may be more classes too. For example the classes can be in order of ' .member_login , .product_services .create_account '

Comment: I didn't understood , why people has downvoted the question , am I missing some basic

Comment: How you are getting three classes on console _In case , user click on button with class create_account` , I get in console create_account singup  header-icon`, which is correct_??

Comment: @sanjeev, if you want specify class why you use one click handler?

Comment: @Grundy , basically based on the class name I have to perform some other complex function

Comment: @sanjeev, so, if you add separate function for each class - you can avoid problem with finding what class clicked :-)

Comment: @sanjeev Then if you have to do specific jobs on specific class just do the job with the jquery event handler on specific class like i told you below : $('body').on('click','.specificClass',function(){//do the job}); and do this for each class...

Comment: @Grundy , yes that too is a good option , I can go with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a separate `click` handler for each class, like so:

```js
// Define all the required classes in an array...
var selectors = ["create_account", "member_login", "product_services"];
// Iterate over the array
$.each(selectors, function(index, selector) {
    // Attach a new click handler per-class. This could be a shared function
    $("."+selector).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(selector); // Logs individual class
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="create_account" href="">Create</a>
<a class="member_login" href="">Login</a>
<a class="product_services" href="">Services</a>
```

If you want you can abstract the *shared* logic out into another function, [like this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnzcbxwh/)

Comment: Downvoter care to explain what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Approach with Data Attributes**

```
<a href='#' class='action-trigger' data-action='Creation'>Create Account</a>

$('.action-trigger').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('action'));
 });
```

**Retrieve Class Based on it Being First**

```
<a href='#' class='create_account singup  header-icon'>Create Account</a>

$('.create_account , .member_login , .product_services').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
});
```

**Alternative Approach with Parameters**

```
<a href='#' class='create_account singup  header-icon'>Create Account</a>

$('.create_account').click(function(){
   MyFunction('CreateAccount');
});

$('.member_login').click(function(){
   MyFunction('MemberLogin');
});

function MyFunction(type)
{
   console.log(type);
}
```

Comment: Using data attributes instead of classes would make good semantic sense. Your second example however is dependant on the order of the classes (so that is a bad idea). The third option defeats the whole *DRY* principle. In all cases a delegated event handler would be more efficient that a selector matching multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

This will always return the list of classes that the element has. You can actually include an 'id' attribute to the element to access it when clicked.

```
<a href='#' class='but' id='create_account'>Button 1</a>

$('.but').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dinesh_feder/2uq5h03j/

Comment: I think the OP wants to know which of '.create_account , .member_login , .product_services' was clicked when there are multiple classes like `<div class="singup  header-icon create_account">` in the triggering element.

Answer (score 0):

There are good solutions put forth using an array of selectors, but here is a solution using the strings of the selectors and the classes of the triggering element.

It's unfortunate that [.selector](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) was removed in jQuery 1.9 or else this would be even simpler. The approach is to get the original selector as an array and intersect it with the array of classes on the triggering element. The result will be the class that triggered the event. Consider this example:

> [".create_account", ".member_login", ".product_services"]
>   [".class1", ".class2", ".create_account"]

Their intersection is:

> [".create_account"]

Here is working code:

```js
var selector = '.create_account, .member_login, .product_services';
$(selector).on("click", { sel: selector.split(", ") }, function(e){

  var classArr = $(this).attr("class").split(" ").map(function(a){ return "."+a; });
  var intersect = $.map(e.data.sel,function(a){return $.inArray(a, classArr) < 0 ? null : a;});

  alert(intersect[0]); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="class1 class2 create_account">class1 class2 create_account</button><br/><button class="class3 product_services class4">class3 product_services class4</button><br/><button class="class5 class6 member_login">class5 class6 member_login</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add the classes into an array and then iterate to it to see if our target has one of those into its class attribute :

```js
var classes = ['.create_account' , '.member_login' , '.product_services'];
 $(classes.join()).click(function(){
   for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
     var classPos = $(this).attr('class').indexOf(classes[i].substring(1));
     if(classPos>-1)
       $('#result').html(classes[i]);
     }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='create_account singup  header-icon'>Create Account</a>
<a href='#' class='member_login singup  header-icon'>Member Login</a>
<a href='#' class='singup  header-icon product_services'>product services</a>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Same as @RGraham : "Downvoter care to explain what's wrong with the answer?"

Answer (score -2):

Well, to take back the Manish Jangir .... example, if you have to retrieve only the concerned class, then why don't you test it? you use jquery so you can use "hasClass" don't you?

```
$('.create_account , .member_login , .product_services').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('create_account')){
        alert('create_account');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('member_login')){
        alert('member_login');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('product_services')){
        alert('product_services');
    }
});
```

This is maybe not a "perfect solution" but it fits your requirements...^^

You can also do it this way with jquery :

```
$('body').on('click','.create_account',function(event){
    alert('.create_account');
    //do your stuff
});
$('body').on('click','.member_login',function(event){
    //...
});
$('body').on('click','.product_services',function(event){
    //...
});
```

this way you just have to add a block if you add a new class that needs an event on click on it... I do not see any more "specific" answer to your question... I always used to do it this way since the way I handle the event on classes can be really different...

Comment: you are indeed correct, but I am looking for a better solution , In case there is no better option , then I have to surely move by your way

Comment: I would remove the `else` parts. It's entirely possible an element has one or more of these classes

Comment: also instead `e.target` you can use `this`

Comment: wth? downvoted ^^ answer fits question requirements.

Comment: Just a side-note, but for *delegated event handlers*, use `document` as your default (if nothing else is closer) and not `'body'`. `'body'` has a bug to do with styling that may cause mouse events not to bubble to it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie maybe you are right, but I remember that there is a reason why I do that, and I think it's dom related. Sometimes, when I work on DOM, I think that elements that are added to DOM do not respond to event if handler is not linked to body... but long time I didn't do this, so I should check :) thx

Comment: A delegated event just needs to be connected to an ancestor *that does not change*. Preferably the closest ancestor that does not change, but document will *always* work (as it is the root DOM element) but as I said, *body has a bug so should be avoided* :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thx for information :) (is that because I never heard about that bug that i was downvoted like that^^ ? :P )

Comment: why would my answer deleted make a better score to someone? oO